# Count number of groups that match SQL condition

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sapb1

I have a Crystal Report with all my records grouped by customer. I also have an SQL command that checks whether the customer has had services, if so then 1 else 0.

When I place this into my report in the group header/footer then as expected I get a 1 or 0 depending on whether the customer has had a service in the time frame or not. All good so far..

Now the problem is here, I need to count the number of groups that have a 1 and place this total in the report header. Whenever I use a sum or a count though I get really high numbers, because even though its showing a 1 or 0, it's instead counting the number of details in the group.

Any thoughts on how to best approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Running total to SUM that formula.
Set the evaluation to once for each group change.

Comment: Hi @MilletSoftware, thanks for your response. I need to place value in my report header which i cant do with a running total.